# How to continue loop inside of Try Catch for Guessing game

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

So my problem is that i don't know how to continue my program when i do the try and catch for input errors. I tried using the "continue;" code after my catch statement but that just loops my program uncontrollably. I need the program to start where it left off after the user does an incorrect input. Any help would be appreciated. Note that this was an assignment BUT I'm going above and beyond by handling junk in my code.

```
      //Import library
      import java.io.*;
      import java.util.*;

      //File name
   public class GuessingGame
   {

//Main throws Input and output error
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    //inputs for users
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner i = new Scanner (System.in);
    //variables for the loop, random number, character and counter
    int guess = 0;
    int rnd;
    char decision;
    boolean loop = false;
    //random number generator
    Random random = new Random();
    rnd = random.nextInt(100) + 1;

    //loops the guess and input
    while (!loop){
        try{
            System.out.println(rnd);
            //prompt the user
            System.out.println(" Please guess a number between 1-100. Press 0 to exit.");
            int num = in.nextInt();
            //if statements

            if (num==0) 
            {
                //when user types '0' it ends the program
                System.exit(0);
                System.out.println("You gave up!.... Reseting program...");
            }
            else if (num>rnd) 
            {
                //prints too big, adds to counter 'guess'
                System.out.println("The number is too big!"); 
                guess++;
            }
            else if (num<rnd)
            {
                //prints too small, adds to counter 'guess'
                System.out.println("The number is too small!"); 
                guess++;
            }
            else 
            {
                //prints correct, adds to counter, dsiplays # of guesses and ends loop
                System.out.println("You guessed the number right!!"); 
                guess++; 
                System.out.print(" # of guesses: " + guess); 
                //Note**: i could've just put 'break;' but the compiler would'nt read the rest                       of the code below
                loop = true;
                //loops the case untill correct input is chosen either 'Y' or 'N'
                while(true){
                    //prompt the user if they want to play again
                    System.out.println(" Would you like to play again? Y/N?");
                    decision = i.nextLine().charAt(0);

                    switch (decision) {
                        case 'Y':
                        case 'y':    
                            //calls main, basically restarts the game
                            GuessingGame.main(args);     
                            break;

                        case 'N':
                        case 'n':
                            System.out.println("Bye!");
                            //exits the program completely
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;

                        default: 
                            //if incorrect input, this prints
                            System.out.println("Please enter a Yes or No <Y/N>");

                    }
                }
            }



        }
        //catches input errors
        catch (Exception e){ 
            System.out.println("Only numbers!!!");
            //GuessingGame.main(args);
            continue;

        } 
       }
       }
```

Comment: Put a `in.next()` in your catch.  `nextInt` is failing when you don't put in a valid int but you're never telling scanner to move past it.  Also, no need for continue at the end of your loop; not a bad guess though.

Comment: As an aside, once you get this working I recommend posting the code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for some good constructive feedback.  I've learned a ton from reading their suggestions, it should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner by default splits the standard input by spaces and keeps an index of how many substrings have been parsed.  The specific method you call (.nextWhatever) will attempt to parse the next string in line to its expected type and will only increase the index if it's successful; if there's no stream left to parse, it will await new input.

The reason your loop is infinite is because it failed to parse the token to an integer and isn't increasing the index.  There are two ways to skip the invalid input.  `nextLine()` will skip the rest of the stream waiting.  For example, if the input was "1 abc 2"

```
in.nextInt(); // equals 1
// in.nextInt() would fail
in.nextLine(); // equals "abc 2" and if put in your catch would clear the stream
```

However, if you want to keep trying subsequent tokens (in this case skip "abc" but try "2", which is valid), `next()` is more appropriate because it will just skip over one token.

```
try(){
  // validate input
  int num = in.nextInt();
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Ignoring your faulty input");
  in.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this move your catch up because you are only testing the input.  Also add in.nextLine() in your catch to eat up the character that is left behind.

```
while (!loop){
  int num;
     try{
                System.out.println(rnd);
                //prompt the user
                System.out.println(" Please guess a number between 1-100. Press 0 to exit.");
                num = in.nextInt();
            }
                catch (Exception e){ 
                    System.out.println("Only numbers!!!");
                    //GuessingGame.main(args);
                    in.nextLine();
                    continue;

                }
```